# Get all keys of a multidimensional dictionary

Tags: objective-c, dictionary

I have a dictionary like:

```
{
dataTypes =     (
            {
        dataType = "datatype1";
        editable = 1;
        maxValue = 300;
        minValue = 0;
        order = 1;
        title = "Title 1";
        type = numeric;
        units = kg;
    },
            {
        dataType = "datatype 2";
        editable = 1;
        maxValue = 300;
        minValue = 0;
        order = 2;
        title = "title2";
        type = numeric;
        units = gm;
    },
            {
        dataType = "datatype3";
        editable = 1;
        maxValue = 300;
        minValue = 20;
        order = 3;
        title = "title3";
        type = numeric;
        units = kg;
    }
);
name = "Name";
order = 1
title = "Title";
}
```

I want to get all keys within this dictionary.

I tried `[myDict allKeys]`, however this is returning only four keys: `DataTypes`, `name`, `order`, `title`.

I want to retrieve all keys: `dataType`, `editable`, `maxvalue`, etc.

Comment: `myArray` isn't an array, it's a dictionary. And that dictionary has 4 keys. The  `dataTypes` key has an array. It's an array of dictionaries.

Comment: okey than can you tell me how can i achieve this?

Comment: Dig down to the dictionary you need and get its keys. There are countless examples of code for this.

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya you want all keys along with name,order, title, datatype, editable, macvalue, minvalue etc...??

Comment: yes....but i want to make method that take arguments as dictionary and return all key within this dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
NSArray *tempArray = [myDict objectForKey:@"dataTypes"];

NSDictionary *tempDictionary = (NSDictionary *)tempArray[0];
```

[tempDictionary allKeys] will have what you want.

Write this method.

```
- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryFromArrayWithinDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary withKey:(NSString *)key{
    NSArray *tempArray = [dictionary objectForKey:key];
    return (NSDictionary *)tempArray[0]; 
}
```

This will return the inner dictionary and simply calling `allKeys' on this dictionary, you will get all the keys you want.

Comment: `[myDict objectForKey:@"dataTypes"]` returns an `NSArray` in this case.

Comment: but what if i want to create method that return key from dictionary? every time key is "dataTypes" is not necessary.

Comment: if you have the dictionary, then you can directly get it from the `allKeys` property.

Comment: Read my question properly..i already tried allKeys but it return only four keys.

Comment: write a method that returns the array of dictionaries by passing the key  to it... then you can get one object from that dictionary and get the keys from `allKeys` property

Answer (score 0):

You need to recursively walk through your dictionary, and through any arrays the dictionary might contain, and so on. This can be nicely done via a `recursiveKeys` method added to all objects, which returns an empty array for objects that are not containers, and walks though the container for objects that are containers:

```
@interface NSObject(MyCategory)
- (NSArray)recursiveKeys;
@end

@implementation NSObject(MyCategory)
- (NSArray)recursiveKeys {
    return @[];
}
@end

@implementation NSArrray(MyCategory)
- (NSArray)recursiveKeys {
    NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (id item in self) {
        [result addObjectsFromArray:[item recursiveKeys]];
    }
    return [result copy]; //return an immutable array
}
@end

@implementation NSSet(MyCategory)
- (NSArray)recursiveKeys {
    NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (id item in self) {
        [result addObjectsFromArray:[item recursiveKeys]];
    }
    return [result copy]; //return an immutable array
}
@end

@implementation NSDictionary(MyCategory)
- (NSArray)recursiveKeys {
    NSMutableArray *result = [self.allKeys mutableCopy];
    for (id key in self) {
        [result addObjectsFromArray:[self[key] recursiveKeys];
    }
    return [result copy]; //return an immutable array
}
@end
```

You can use it like this:

```
NSArray *keys = myDictionary.recursiveKeys;
```

Please pardon any syntax errors, I don't have at this time an Xcode in front of me, I simply typed the code here on SO.

Comment: Won't this appear to flatten the multi-dimensional dictionary?

Comment: @trojanfoe this will return an array of strings (if all keys are strings), you might call it flattening, if you'd consider embedded dictionaries as multi-level arrays of strings :)